# Symony2, doctrine datetime in microseconds

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, timestamp

In symfony2 I have created entity with created and updated parameters:

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Serializer\Expose
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated;
```

When I update schema below queries are executed:

```
ALTER TABLE review ADD created TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE review ADD updated TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL;
```

How can I store datetime with microseconds into the postgreSql database?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with your parameters being of PHP DateTime type (`\DateTime`).

Because PHP DateTime does not support fractional seconds. It is reported on first comment at [PHP DateTime documentation page](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php). I was surprised myself.

I know this won't solve your problem, but I have just spent several hours trying to figure out what is hapening with my microseconds.

Comment: `DateTime` supports microseconds since `5.2.2`.